# installing openAOS 2.3.5 on Archos 5IT?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

I found there is people installing openAOS 2.3.5 on Archos 5IT, but I haven't seen any website detailing the instructions on how to do it. Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [openAOS site](http://dev.openaos.org/wiki/SupportedDevices), the Archos 5 is supported. So I would think that there would be a download for an update package for that specific device. This is how others do it. The steps to install on any of the devices should be the same (or close) the only thing you would need is the install package. I could not find downloads on the openAOS site.